# Flex box is not working in Safari 5.1

Tags: css, safari

I am getting sooooo frustrated .... using flex box for my table and its working great is chrome and firefox but not in Safari. My Safari version is 5.1. I tried to find out the solution over the net but cudnt find it. People mostly asked to use display: -webkit-box but its not working too. Any magic trick ?????????

I already tried almost all the fixes that has been told over the net. Here is my code

```
.my-table ul li {
     display: -webkit-flex;
     display: -webkit-box;
     display: -ms-flex;
     display: flex;
}
```

Comment: "Is not working" is not a good problem description. Tell us what you want to happen and what happens instead. Ideally, show a screenshot on which you incidate the issue. And above all, provide a complete snippet that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: ...but no-one uses Safari 5..it's a dead browser.

Comment: @Paulie_D There are a lot of questions about Safari 5.1.7 on this site. Apparently it's not as dead as you believe.

Answer (score 2):

Flexbox works well in safari 5.1.7

I used it for all my project but I notice that some of the flex properties didn't work. Specifically flex-wrap, flex-direction, flex-grow, and etc.

```
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
```

Comment: I have already tried all of it as I mentioned in my problem but all these is just not working. Need some magic fix

Comment: flexbox i believe is only supported on Safari 10+ as per http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Comment: @Anirudha look at the page you linked to the comment. Safari v3.1 - 6 is partially supported :) Some of the flexbox property doesn't work.

Comment: @Anirudha you didn't expand the browser versions fully.